# Apex Chart with Bootstrap/Semantic-UI are not compatible？

Tags: visualforce, css

I tried to use Bootstrap/Semantic-UI in VF Page.

First, I created some apex:chart. It works fine. And I started styling page with Bootstrap/Semantic-UI.

Then my line, bar, areas all gone. And only X-Axis and Y-Axis left.

Did anyone meet same problem？

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same problem when using apex chart in visual force page and bootstrap at the same time. But found a solution and it worked. 
You may also try that. Try adding below code to the CSS.

```
[hidden], template
    {
        display:block !important;
    }
```

Comment: Interesting! I think SFDC fixed the problem. When I put semantic.JS back, it display now. ( I didn't add this css. )